# Create a Profile model for a specific user (Django 4.0)?

Tags: python, django, web

Does anybody know how to create a Profile for the user upon completion of the registration form??? (Django)

views.py:

```
class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm #Imported from forms
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        return response
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #rpg_class = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)    

                                                                      
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I tried this and it doesnt work, It says something like

```
Internal Server Error: /CodeRPGappMain/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: CodeRPGappMain_profile.bio
```

Making a Profile manually in the admin isnt going to work So I need it to create itself automatically every time a user signs up, it already creates a user bc of Djangos built in stuff but I need to create its custom model Profile for the user upon completion

Comment: Why wont constructing this in the admin work?

Comment: Well it will temporarily, but assume I have more than one user and I don't want to be at my computer all day making profiles for each individual user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this (likely) does not work is because your `Profile` has a `bio` field that is not [**`null=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#null), and has no [**`default=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#default), hence when creating your `Profile`, it has no value to fill in for `bio`.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance, bio='')
```

It is possible that there are additional fields that you will need to set manually, or you define a `default=…` value.

Regardless, using signals is often *not* a good idea. Signals for example do not work when you create or update items in bulk. You can just use the view and override the admin, *without* signals:

```
class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm  # Imported from forms
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        Profile.objects.create(user=self.object, bio='')
        return response
```

and in the admin with:

```
# app_name/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

admin.site.unregister(User)


@admin.register(User)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if obj._state.adding:
            Profile.objects.create(user=obj, bio='')
```

Comment: Thanks for this, It ended up being that I didnt make migrations, However I tried your approach and was thrown an error because "unregister is not a thing" or so it says.

Comment: @userr554: that was a typo yes, `admin.site.unregister`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need to use `save()` method after `create()`. The `create()` method creates and saves an object in a single step.

The problem here: `sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: CodeRPGappMain_profile.bio`. It seems like you played with the Profile model and somehow added bio field.

How to fix it?

If you don't care about your data, just delete `.sqlite3` db file and all migrations inside migrations folders (everything except `__init__.py`). Then `makemigrations()` and `migrate()`, everything will work.

Or, add `bio field` back to the model. You can provide `default=''` or `null=True`  to don't care about initial value and avoid the problem.

Comment: Hey, I wish It wasn't this stupid, but I actually just forgot to make migrations. You reminded me